# This error happen either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

I am getting an error saying This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). here is code btw i am new to express here is code

```
 // We import the client constructor to initialize a new client
 //We create a new client

const reactionRoleManager = new ReactionRoleManager(client, {
 //We create a reaction role manager that'll handle everything related to reaction roles
 storage: true, // Enable reaction role store in a Json file
 path: __dirname + '/roles.json', // Where will save the roles if store is enabled
 mongoDbLink: 'url mongoose link', // See here to see how setup mongoose: https://github.com/IDjinn/Discord.js-Collector/tree/dev/examples/reaction-role-manager/Note.md & https://medium.com/@LondonAppBrewery/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-windows-4ee4b3493514
});

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('ready');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
 const client = message.client;
 const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
 // Example
 // >createReactionRole @role :emoji: MessageId
 if (message.content.startsWith('>createReactionRole')) {
  const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (!role)
   return message
    .reply('You need mention a role')
    .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 1_000 }));

  const emoji = args[1];
  if (!emoji)
   return message
    .reply('You need use a valid emoji.')
    .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 1_000 }));

  const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(args[2] || message.id);
  if (!role)
   return message
    .reply('Message not found!')
    .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 1_000 }));

  reactionRoleManager.addRole({
   message: msg,
   role,
   emoji,
  });
  message.reply('Done').then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 500 }));
 }
});
// have an error saying This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

Please help me

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=This+error+originated+either+by+throwing+inside+of+an+async+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Always [Search the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=This+error+originated+either+by+throwing+inside+of+an+async+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking

Comment: "*This error originated by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block*" - well, did you try adding a `catch` block to your function, or add `.catch()` calls to your promise chains?

Comment: And guys i am new to coding in discord.js so i dont know where i should add the catch block but i will try and @Bergi can you please answer whole code

Comment: And guys if you are gonna answer please send whole code or just send the part of code because i dont know where to place the catch

Comment: You put it after a promise, usually sending message, deleting message, or doing something that requires permissions. Like this: `message.channel.send('hey').catch(console.log)`